# What's the Japanese word for the stuff after the credits of a movie?

Tags: word-requests

In English, we call footage that plays after the credits of a movie a "stinger". See, for example, [the wiktionary entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stinger), definition 8:

> A scene shown on films or television shows after the credits.

What would you call this in Japanese? I guess you could describe it as エンドロールの後の映像, but is there a more concise / punchier way of referring to it?

Comment: "is there a more concise / punchier way of referring to it?" And if there is, how widely used/known is it? Because I've never heard 'stinger' used like that before in English!

Comment: @Ash I've heard it a fair bit in my corner of the US, and it sees use on sites like [mediastinger](http://www.mediastinger.com/).

Comment: @Ash: I've heard it, but only because I've stumbled across the same Wikipedia entry.  Kind of reminds me of http://xkcd.com/978/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is usually called 「おまけカット」.

When it consists of bloopers, it is called 「[NG集]{エヌジーしゅう}」.

Comment: おまけカットって初めて聞きました。よう知ってはりますねえ。さすが年の功・・・

Comment: 俳優やもん、これぐらい知ってまんがな。で、誰がシルバー世代やねん！